# How to verify user input without loop in java swing gui

Tags: java, swing, loops, user-interface

My previous question I asked why my GUI was not doing anything once I pressed the button and the issue found was that I had a infinite loop which only finished once the user input the correct value. But after finding out you can not have those type of infinite loops in a GUI, how does one verify a users input then?

I currently changed it to a for loop and the "break" condition is that the variable finished is equal to true. It gets equal to true when it goes into one of the if statements. However this still seems to be seen as a infinite loop.

I can not seem to see anything online about how to do loops in a GUI like the one above.

GUI class with Main:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */

public class TrainingProgrammeGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

static PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new GUITextOutputStream(TrainingProgrammeGUI.jTextArea1));
double startTimer = System.nanoTime();
double stopTimer = 0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Player gameCharacter = null;
Teacher teacher = null;
int finishedProgram = 0;   
int userChoice = -1;  
boolean inRoom = true;

/**
 * Creates new form TrainingProgrammeGUI
 */
public TrainingProgrammeGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    filler1 = new javax.swing.Box.Filler(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0), new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 32767));
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("CIA Training Programme");

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Game: ");

    jButton1.setText("Start Game");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setText("What is this game?");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("Type Here: ");

    jButton4.setText("Exit");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Inspect 2");

    jButton5.setText("Inspect 1");

    jButton6.setText("Inspect 3");

    jButton7.setText("Choose Suspect");

    jButton9.setText("Enter Room");
    jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 55, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addGap(515, 515, 515))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(159, 159, 159))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(166, 166, 166)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap())
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jButton7)
                                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 109, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 487, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10))))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(232, 232, 232))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                    .addComponent(filler1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 226, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                    .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
     TrainingProgrammeGUI programme = new TrainingProgrammeGUI();
     programme.setVisible(true);
}

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    System.out.print("\nThank you for using our training programme!");
    System.exit(0);
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.out.println("1/2");
    System.setOut(printStream);
    System.setErr(printStream);
    System.out.println("2/2");


    System.out.println("==================================\n"+
                       "* WELCOME TO CATCH ME IF YOU CAN *\n"+
                       "==================================\n");                                     

    userChoice = TrainingProgramme.checkInputWithPhrase("1.) Start Game\n2.) What is this game?\n3.) Quit", 1, 3);
    teacher = new Teacher("John Doe", "Teacher");
    gameCharacter = teacher.introductionLines(); // teacher reads a few lines and asks questions then returns Player class
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.setOut(printStream);
    System.setErr(printStream);

    System.out.println("\n+===========================================================+");
    System.out.println("|This game was created to help train our new junior recruits|");
    System.out.println("+===========================================================+\n\n");

    System.out.println("Objective: Gather evidence by looking for clues\n"+ 
                       "and once you are done go back to the room to guess \n"+
                       "which suspect did it. Suspects are provided once you have\n"+ 
                       "went back to the room and decided to guess who did the crime!\n");
}                                        

private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

}                                        

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.Box.Filler filler1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
public static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

GUITextOutputStream:

```
/*
 * A class that redirects output to GUI
 */
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */

public class GUITextOutputStream extends OutputStream {

private JTextArea textArea;

public GUITextOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
    setTextArea(textArea);
}

/**
 * @return the textArea
 */
public JTextArea getTextArea() {
    return textArea;
}

/**
 * @param textArea the textArea to set
 */
public void setTextArea(JTextArea textArea) {
    this.textArea = textArea;
}

@Override
public void write(int i) throws IOException {
    textArea.append(String.valueOf((char) i)); //Redirects text to the GUI text area;
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
}
```

Player Class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Player {

    private String name;

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * @param cluesLeft
     */
    public Player(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Teacher Class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Teacher extends NPC {


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    private HashMap<String, String> items = new HashMap<>(); //Key is item name and value is item clue 
    private List<String> gameDialogue; // Holds all text information for chooseWhoDidIt() method

    public Teacher(String name, String role) {
        super(name, role);
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            gameDialogue = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("GameDialogue.txt"));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found, exact error: "+ e);
        }

        try { 
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ItemInspection.txt"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //This reads in the item (as the key) and the clue (as the value) from "ItemInspection.exe"
               String key = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '));
               String value = line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1);

               items.put(key, value);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found, exception: "+ e);
        } 
    }

      /**
     * @return the suspectInfo
     */
    public List<String> getGameDialogue() {
        return gameDialogue;
    }

    /**
     * @param suspectInfo the suspectInfo to set
     */
    public void setGameDialogue(List<String> suspectInfo) {
        this.gameDialogue = suspectInfo;
    }

     /**
     * @return the items
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * @param items the items to set
     */
    public void setItems(HashMap<String, String> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    /**
     * prints out introduction and welcome lines as well as asking player for player name 
     * then creates and returns a Player object 
     * @return Player
     */
    public Player introductionLines() {
        Player gameCharacter;

        String characterName = "";

        System.out.println(TrainingProgramme.obtainGameDialogue(43, 44, null, this.getGameDialogue()));
        pause("long");
        System.out.println(TrainingProgramme.obtainGameDialogue(45, 45, null, this.getGameDialogue()));

        characterName = scan.nextLine();
        if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(characterName)) {
            characterName = characterName + "I can not choose";
        }
        gameCharacter = new Player(characterName, 2);

        System.out.println(TrainingProgramme.obtainGameDialogue(46, 46, null, this.getGameDialogue()) + " " + gameCharacter.getName());
        pause("short");
        System.out.println(TrainingProgramme.obtainGameDialogue(47, 47, null, this.getGameDialogue()));
        pause("short");
        System.out.println(TrainingProgramme.obtainGameDialogue(48, 52, null, this.getGameDialogue()));
        pause("kindoflong");
        System.out.println();

        return gameCharacter;
    }
}
```

NPC:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication2;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class NPC {

    private String name;
    private String role;

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * @param role
     */
    public NPC(String name, String role) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setRole(role);
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the role
     */
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    /**
     * @param role the role to set
     */
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    /**
     * Pauses all code for a certain length to allow player to read
     * @param length
     */
    public void pause(String length) { //Calling pause results in Thread.sleep(time) and time being bassed of the string provided

        if ("veryshort".equalsIgnoreCase(length)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } 
        } else if("short".equalsIgnoreCase(length)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } 
        } else if("kindoflong".equalsIgnoreCase(length)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } 
        } else if ("verylong".equalsIgnoreCase(length)) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(22000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

TrainingProgramme:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class TrainingProgramme {

    /**
     *
     */
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    static PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new GUITextOutputStream(TrainingProgrammeGUI.jTextArea1));

    /**
     * Checks (and makes sure) that users input is valid whilst also printing supplied String each loop
     * @param phrase
     * @return int
     */
    public static int checkInputWithPhrase(String phrase, int firstOption, int lastOption) {//Make sure input given is valid 

        boolean correctInput = false;
        int userChoice = 0;
        for (boolean finished = false; finished != true;) { //Makes sure user input correct value
            boolean exception = false;               // checks if an exception was caught in the current loop
            try {                                       
                System.out.println(phrase);
                userChoice = scan.nextInt();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("\nPlease input a number only!\n");
                    System.out.println("\nError code for developer: " + e + "\n");
                    exception = true;
                }
                if (exception == false) {
                    if (userChoice >= firstOption && userChoice <= lastOption) {
                        finished = true;
                        return userChoice;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("\nPlease input a number within the above range!\n");
                    }
                }
                if (exception == true) { // clear buffer is user has previously inputed wrong value
                        scan.next();
                }
        }
        return 0;
    } 

        /**
     * method reads, saves and returns data from a list (which  is comprised of all text from "GameDialogue.txt")
     * @param start
     * @param end
     * @param doesItContain
     * @return String
     */
    public static String obtainGameDialogue (int start, int end, String doesItContain, List<String> dialogue) { 
        String finalString = "";
        boolean firstLoop = true;

        for (int x = start; x <= end; x++) {
            if (start == end && firstLoop) { //If only one line will be read 
                finalString = finalString + dialogue.get(x);
            } else {
                if (doesItContain != null && doesItContain.equalsIgnoreCase(dialogue.get(x))) { //if doesItContain has a String, which matches a string in the list ,(and not null) then the loop will add two new lines at the end of that String (instead of one)
                finalString = finalString + dialogue.get(x);
                finalString = finalString + "\n\n"; //creates a new paragraph by making a gap
                } else {
                        if (x != end) { 
                            finalString = finalString + dialogue.get(x);
                            finalString = finalString + "\n"; 
                        } else { // does not add new line if x is equal to the last line (end) 
                            finalString = finalString + dialogue.get(x);
                        }
                } 
            }
        }
        finalString = "\n" + finalString;
        return finalString;
    }

}
```

Apologies if I missed some code, just comment below if I did but I believe this is everything. I have made it as minimal as possible but a lot of my classes have methods that link to other classes.

Comment: GUIs tend to be event driven, something happens, you respond to it.  In you case, you'd probably be waiting for the `ActionEvent` to occur on the button.  Once this does occur, you'd verify the input and take appropriate action, which might be waiting for the event to occur again

Comment: Please share your [code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) in the form of a [MCVE](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I appreciate the help! Apologies if I am not getting this as GUI is very new to me. So once they input something into the text field, I then capture that and verify it and if it is not verified I ask the question again? Think this way I could fix my issue thank you :) However, I will still post my code.

Comment: @D.B. Great suggestion, and a tip: `[mre]` in a comment auto-expands to [mre].

Comment: I have added the minimal reproducible example, many of my classes have methods that link to other classes so apologies about that. But once you run it you will see that nothing happens when you click a button. For the start button it only runs the first line of code then nothing else.

Comment: I can't do anything with your code, because you used a GUI builder.  When you're learning about GUI development, you should code the GUI by hand without the help of a GUI builder, so you understand what's going on in your code.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, albeit rather annoying as I was told to use a GUI builder in the begging haha.